# XSLT or BizTalk-Mapping generated from Excel

Tags: converters, biztalk

Does anybody know if there is a tool which can convert an Excel document (or something similiar, it really does not have to be Excel) to an XSLT document or to a BizTalk Mapping (actually here it also must not be a BizTalk specific document).

If there is no tool for this, does anybody know references about this theme? I know this is a really common question, but unfortunatelly I can not be more specific. I need this for research and preparing to develop a software.

Or at least maybe someone has any keywords which might help me to research, because actually I really don't know how this problem can be described.

Answer (score 1):

No, what you are asking for does not exist.

In practice, the crosswalk is maintained by a Business user using a tool appropriate for them, almost always Excel.

The developer then takes this and implements a BizTalk Map based on the information provided by the Business.  It is never a direct translation so realistically, a tool is simply not possible.

What you can use at ship time is the BizTalk Map Documenter: http://biztalkmapdoc.codeplex.com/